# You only have one commit incorrectly signed off

Tags: git, github

i have recently started open source contributing during my first pull request I don't faced an issue like this but after then I am facing this issue again and again
[image]

this is the image of detail section

[image]

steps I followed were

1- made separate branch and checkout it

2- done some changes in the code

3- stage changes using git add filename

4- commit changes using git commit -m"bugfix"

5- pushed the changes using git push origin deadline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, `git commit --signoff` or `git commit -s` is a way in which you add a trail message to the commit message saying that the commit is signed off by you.

On step #4 mentioned above, you need to use `git commit -s -m "yourCommitmessageHere"` so that the DCO step is successful.

This feature is used to keep a track of who has done what on a particular repository. Since it is an open source contribution that you are doing, please ask the people who are reviewers for your pull request/merge request about any commit message format that they want you to adhere to also so that such issues don't crop up again for you later on.